# How does Cross Site Scripting (XSS) work exactly?

Tags: security

On WordCamp Europe I attended the talk by Brad Williams on Writing Secure WordPress Code and I would like to make sure that I implement these tips in my own code.

In his [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/williamsba/writing-secure-wordpress-code) he gives the following example:

BAD:

```
<?php 
    $title = "<script> alert( 'Hello Europe!' );</script>";
?>

<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>
```

GOOD:

```
<?php 
    $title = "<script> alert( 'Hello Europe!' );</script>";
?>

<h1><?php echo esc_html( $title ); ?></h1>
```

Although I realise that this is a very simple example, my question is *how* - or perhaps more important **when** - would someone be able to add something like `<script> alert( 'Hello Europe!' );</script>` in the first place?

Comment: Hi Piet, this is off-topic since XSS affects any client-side scripts and not just WordPress ones. Your best off using Google or YouTube for some basics  on how XSS works and then reading this comprehensive list: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: allright, will try to find info on it on my own then. Thanks for the link

Comment: You can drop into chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop and well...chat, I'm usually in there during the day.

Comment: the WordPress context lies in the fact that (see my comment on @Sander Koedood) it seems that WordPress already strips out "dangerous" strings, whether a developer escapes the strings or not.

Comment: Ok , we can vote to re-open your question if you re-word it along the lines of explaining what `esc_html` does, but these questions might have been asked, see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=esc_html .

Comment: Thing is that I know what `esc_html` does, my original question was **how** or **when** would someone (a hacker) be able to insert scripts given that WordPress Core **seems** to strip out unsafe characters by default? If a hacker already has gained access to your site, then what would the point be of xss instead of just simply destroying your site?

Comment: XSS is client based (generally speaking), a hacker does not need access to your site, so if a theme or plugin is not escaping javascript they can XSS the browser, this is very common with themes and plugins, much more than I think people realize.

Comment: Well, that is basically the answer @Wyck :) So for plugins that on the frontend have input fields and things like that it is of utmost importance to escape strings and naturally for themes' search fields, contact- and comment forms and any other frontend input areas, correct?

Comment: Everything that is input/output should be valid and sanitized always, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Comment: @Wyck from the Codex article you linked to: "It's important to note that most WordPress functions properly prepare the data for output, and you don't need to escape again." I understand better now, thx for all the input here!

Answer (score 0):

Though I am no expert in XSS, I do know some of the ways someone can abuse these techniques.

For example, I was once pointed to the fact that visitors were able to execute javascript via the search field of a website, because the input of the search field didn't get stripped of it's html tags (like the example above actually does). This way, people were able to get valuable information about the server, by executing certain scripts via the search field.

As I said, I am no expert, so I don't know what can actually be achieved through XSS. I do know you're better of securing your website from the risk of finding out.

Apart from that, Google is your best friend.

I hope this was helpfull, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your input Sander. Your example (input field for Search) is a good one, but those type of fields are already secured by WordPress Core by default, right? Today I tried  to put scripts in a few widgets I developed without escaping code in mind while I was developing, but also there WordPress just strips out the "dangerous" parts. Hence my original question: if Core already protects everything no matter whether you escape strings in your plugins or not, then what is all the fuss about? Of course at the same time I appreciate there are exceptions, depending on the type of plugin...

Comment: As a matter of fact, the wordpress installation where the search field was an issue, was at least a WordPress 3.3 version. I'm not sure whether it has actually been protected by now, since I regret to say that I'm not developing in WordPress very much anymore lately. Worth checking out maybe...